# c# class internal setter and PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid, internal, access-modifiers

I have Winform App and there is PropertyGrid on the Form. Person class has property (Age) with internal setter. Why that property is ReadOnly on the PropertyGrid? Logically PropertyGrid is member of the same assembly and internals are accessible to assembly members.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    internal int Bio { get; set; }

    private int age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        internal set { age = value; }
    }

    public string Location { get; internal set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ProperyGrid is in its own assembly (`System.Windows.Forms.dll`) separate to your assembly.

Ergo it does not have access to properties, methods or fields that are designated internal in **your** assembly.

Merely referencing both `Person` and `PropertyGrid` from within the same assembly as where the `Person` is defined, will not make the `Age` setter visible in the `System.Windows.Forms.dll`

Also, `PropertyGrid` most likely uses reflection similar to this:

```
object obj = this.SelectedObject;
Type type = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach(PropertyInfo pInfo in props)
{
    if (pInfo.CanWrite)
    { 
           // mark as read/write
    }
    else
    {
         // mark as read-only
    }
}
```

Retrieving only `public` properties. The `Age` prpperty would be returned, but marked with `CanWrite == false`

Comment: So, you mean there is no any workaround for that? Thanks.